# $L = \begin{cases} M & \text{on }\; A\\ N & \text{on} \; A^c \end{cases}$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

In Durrett's probability theory and examples, it asks suppose $M \le N$ are stopping times. If $A \in\mathcal{F}_M$, then
$$L = \begin{cases} M & \text{on }\; A\\ N & \text{on} \; A^c \end{cases}$$
is a stopping time.

To show that $L$ is a stopping time, I believe what I need to show is that $ \{L= n \}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. I'm not sure how we can write $\{ L = n\}$ in terms of $M$ and $N$. What I have is
$$\{ L = n \} = ( \{ M = n\} \cap A) \cup ( \{ N = n \} \cap A^c)$$
Since RHS is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable, we see that $\{ L = n\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable.

However, the textbook gives us a completely different proof where it states
$$\{ N = n\} = (\{L = n\} \cap A) \cup \bigcup_{m=1}^n (\{ L = m\} \cap \{ M = n\} \cap A^c)$$
I can see how we can write $\{ N = n\} = (\{ L = n \} \cap A) \cup (\{ L = n\} \cap A^c)$ but how do we get $\bigcup_{m=1}^n (\{ L = m\} \cap \{ M = n\} \cap A^c)$?

Comment: The textbook's proof that you have related looks like nonsense.  Are you sure you copied it correctly? On the other hand your argument is fine; the containment $\mathcal F_M\subset\mathcal F_N$ follows because $M\le N$ (and is not "assumed").

Comment: @JohnDawkins It's from the solutions and it could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof assumes that $\mathcal F_M \subseteq \mathcal F_N$ which gives $A \in \mathcal F_N$ and hence $(N=n)\cap A^{c} \in \mathcal F_n$. The proof in the  book does not assume this result and it uses  only the definition of stopping times.

Comment: hmm I see. But how do you get $\bigcup_{m=1}^n ( \{ L =m\} \cap \{ M = n\} \cap A^c)$ from $(\{ L = n\} \cap A^c)$ ? Additionally, the proof in the book only shows that $\{ N= n\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. How is that equivalent to $\{ L = n\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable?

Comment: @MoneyBall  Since $M \leq N$ the conditions $L=m$ and $M=n$ imply  $m \leq n$  on $A^{c}$ so then union is over $m$ from $1$ to $n$.